# How to stop the app crashing when String is empty

Tags: java, android, crash

The app crash when there is no text ! 
I don't have what 'if' to put to fix that !
Thanks you

```
enter  TextView TotalTextView;
EditText EnterPercentage;
EditText EnterPrice;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    TotalTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TotalTextView);
    EnterPercentage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EnterPercentage);
    EnterPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EnterPrice);
    Button CalcBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CalcBtn);


    CalcBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                float percentage = Float.parseFloat(EnterPercentage.getText().toString());
                float prix = Float.parseFloat(EnterPrice.getText().toString());
                float dec = percentage / 100;
                float total = prix - dec * Float.parseFloat(EnterPrice.getText().toString());

                TotalTextView.setText(String.format("%.2f", total));


        }
    });
```

Thank for your answer, I am a begineer so... Thanks !

```
if (EnterPercentage.getText().equals("")) {

                float percentage = Float.parseFloat(EnterPercentage.getText().toString());
                float prix = Float.parseFloat(EnterPrice.getText().toString());
                float dec = percentage / 100;
                float total = prix - dec * Float.parseFloat(EnterPrice.getText().toString());
                TotalTextView.setText(String.format("%.2f", total));


            } else {
```

}

the button don't do anything but the app doesn't crash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We check the length of the String... when it's 0 then we do nothing. When the String > 0 your code is running.

Like:

```
            if (EnterPercentage.getText().trim().toString().length() == 0 || EnterPrice.getText().toString().length() == 0 ) {
                //Textfields are empty.
                Log.d("Error","Fields are empty");
            } else {
                //Textfield is full
                float percentage = Float.parseFloat(EnterPercentage.getText().toString());
                float prix = Float.parseFloat(EnterPrice.getText().toString());
                float dec = percentage / 100;
                float total = prix - dec * Float.parseFloat(EnterPrice.getText().toString());
                TotalTextView.setText(String.format("%.2f", total));
            }
```

Comment: If I want the app to do anything when the String is empty, what I have to say on "else" ?

Comment: What ever you want.

Comment: @Tim, I'm sorry, but this is not how you compare String objects, as indicated by Mike's link.

Comment: Hey ! I tried but I don't know why I have the problem with your brand new code !

Comment: Sry. Try it again

Comment: Hum.. Actually, the app doesn't crash when the cases are empties but nothing happens when I put number.... I worked before :(

Comment: What do you mean exactly??

Comment: I mean the button doesn't work now, even if I enter numbers in my EditText ! But the app doesn't crash when I don't put  anything in my EditText...

Comment: There isn't error message, and the log don't say anything about that...

Comment: if (EnterPercentage.getText().equals("")) {

                } else {
                    float percentage = Float.parseFloat(EnterPercentage.getText().toString());
                    float prix = Float.parseFloat(EnterPrice.getText().toString());
                    float dec = percentage / 100;
                    float total = prix - dec * Float.parseFloat(EnterPrice.getText().toString());
                    TotalTextView.setText(String.format("%.2f", total));
                }

But the app crash when I don't put numbers as yesterday

Comment: I understand the Problem now. I post a new answer tomorrow

Comment: I changed the code a little bit. But I tested it and it works. When your EnterPrecentage and EnterPrice is empty nothing is done. When both are full your code is running. When only one is full nothing is done. Have fun with the code. When you have problems you can write again :). Maybe you can accept my aswer?? :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to check (obviously) your string. The **if** that your code is missing is :

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(EnterPercentage.getText()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(EnterPrice.getText())) {
// YOUR CODE
}
```

Good luck with android development.
Questions was already posted

Comment: You're calling `isNullOrEmpty()` on `EnterPrice`. Did you mean `getText()`?

Comment: Better code since it will also work with null string objects.

Answer (score 1):

You surely got a NullPointerException. That's because the text is `null` and you put a `.toString()` after.

Try this:

```
float percenteage = 0;
float prix = 0;

if (EnterPercentage.getText() != null)
    percenteage = Float.parseFloat(EnterPercentage.getText().toString());
if (EnterPrice.getText() != null)
    prix = Float.parseFloat(EnterPercentage.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to validate before trying to convert to float

```
float percentage = getFloat();
private float getFloat(){
    float fRet = 0.0f;
    if(your validation here){
        fRet = Float.parseFloat(EnterPercentage.getText().toString());;
    }
    return fRet;
}
```